# Flutter & Provider : How do I make my StreamProvider listen to two different values?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, provider, state-management

Let's say I have the following code. The code below only listen to one value : `AuthService().user`. How do I make my provider listen to another value? Let's call that value : `isVoted`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<SystemUser>.value(

      value: AuthService().user,

      child: MaterialApp(---))
}
```

I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge those two streams to one Stream with StreamGroup and listen to that.

docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/StreamGroup-class.html

In your case:

```
Stream<Object> streamGroup = StreamGroup.merge([AuthService().user, isVoted]);

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Object>.value(

    value: streamGroup,

    child: MaterialApp(---))
}
```

Comment: How about sth like


`Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<SystemUser>.value(

      value: AuthService().user,
      
       StreamProvider<IsVoted>.value(

      value: isVoted,

      child: MaterialApp(---)))
}`

Comment: You can use MultiProvider: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html

Comment: Multiprovider( provider: [StreamProvider<SystemUser>(create: (_) => Authservice().user), StreamProivder<IsVoted>(.create: (_) => isVoted) ] );